# Trouble Reading Bin File Output of NASM through a Hex Converter

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-64, machine-code

On Ubuntu 17.10.1 x86_64

I was interested in the way that different assemblers assemble assembly code (namely NASM), to see if I could build a mini-assembler as a mini project.

So I wrote some very simple assembly commands:

test.asm

```
mov ax, 48
mov bx, 48
add ax, bx
```

I assembled the file with no optimizations into a bin file (nasm without -f defaults to bin):

```
nasm -O0 test.asm
```

And I wrote some java code to turn the resulting file output into hex digits:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class hex{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("test");
        int i = 0;
        while(true){
            i = fr.read();
            if(i == -1) break;
            String s = toHex(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
                System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
            }
        }
    }
    public static String toHex(int dec){
        String output = "";
        int largest = 1;
        int dec2 = dec;
        while(dec2 >= 16){
            dec2 /= 16;
            largest++;
        }
        for(int i = largest-1; i>=0; i--){
            output += hex(dec, i);
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static String hex(int dec, int index){
        String output = "";
        if(dec < 16) output = "0";
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            dec /= 16;
        }
        dec %= 16;
        if(dec > 10) output += (char)(dec+55);
        else output += dec;
        return output;
    }
}
```

But when I run hex, it outputs FF FD 30 00 FF FD 30 00 01 FF FD!

The problem with this?

-mov seems to always convert to FFFD[value]00 for values regardless of the first parameter, and always converts to FFFDFFFD if 2 registers are used regardless of which registers are used

-going forward from that, add is always 01FFFD regardless of what registers were used in the actual asm file wrote (I tried add with multiple different parameters and ended up with the same "01 FF FD")

Other inconsistencies:

-jmp and call in machine code don't use the number inputted

-div and mul are the same in machine code (FFFDFFFD), regardless of parameters inputted in the .asm file

NOTE: I did not use objdump -d [file] because it does not recognize bin files, and I am doing this with bin files, not elf64.

Comment: You can use objdump with flat binary files too. Also there are tons of hex dump programs. Finally, `nasm` itself can produce a text listing for you. Oh, and I am pretty sure there is some built-in java way to print hex. But have an upvote for attempting to do stuff yourself :)

Comment: gives an error when I run objdump -d [bin file name]

Comment: objdump: test: File format not recognized

Comment: `objdump -b binary -m i386 -M i8086,intel  -D `. Consult `objdump --help` or `man objdump`. Alternatively, `nasm -l /dev/stdout ...`

Comment: thank you!!! I wonder why the java program outputted "FFFD[value]00" for a mov command when objdump outputted actual varying hex values for the first parameter value other than FFFD.. maybe my program has a bug haha

Comment: Your java code is of very low quality, at first I though I will try to find the bug, but after quick read through it I suggest you to just delete it (or if you know some experienced Java programmer, get a chat with him to see how many things are weird/ineffective/ugly, and some probably even wrong) ... there's no point to fix it, it's +1 for effort, but keep practising and learning. :)

Comment: I have to agree with @Ped7g, that Java code is pretty messy and overcomplicated.  This is normal for a beginner, though.  Writing terrible code doesn't make you a bad person, it just means you have more to learn, but this is pretty ugly / bad code (even if it wasn't apparently buggy) :P.  For example, you don't need 2 separate functions to turn a byte into 2 hex digits!   (Also note that your system should have a plain hex-dump command installed, like `hexdump -C foo.bin`, and you can use that to check your Java implementation.)

Comment: yep, problem was my java code. I attempted to turn the output of the objdump back into machine code using the same system and objdump gave arbitrary commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while (and looking back on this java code I do find that it is overcomplicated quite a bit), I found that the issue was quite small; I needed a FileInputStream instead of a FileReader. FileInputStreams are capable of reading binary files while FileReaders are more suitable for human-readable files. And just to prove my point, FileInputStreams are capable of reading data into byte arrays while FileReaders can only read data in the form of char arrays and CharBuffers (and chars in Java are very different from bytes). Hope this helps someone.